# Which technology stack to use for car pooling over web and mobile

Tags: scala, mongodb, node.js, redis, lift

I want to start working on a project where I want to build a intranet website and mobile app for people working in my office for car pooling. The basic idea is that if anyone is interested in looking for someone to carpool with should make a posting of going from A to B at time X.People can then reply to it.

I've narrowed down my option to Scala+Lift+MongoDB or Node.JS+Redis/MongoDB+HTML5. I don't know which one is better or worse for the problem I have mentioned. Also looking at developing mobile apps for the same application where people can send carpool request over their phones.Looking for a stack which can complement the mobile development also.

I know there are various solutions for this, but I'm looking to learn something new and exciting and have fun while developing it.

Comment: Use whatever your most skilled with

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only requirement that influences the technology stack is "looking to learn something new and exciting and have fun while developing it" (just as broofa said).

However I have no idea how he came from that requirement to JavaScript.

- Yes it is more marketable
- Yes there are way more people that know it.
- Yes you'll need it any way.

But is JavaScript in anyway interesting as a language? Not much I'd say. Any nice unique (or at least rare) concepts? To me it looks like programming in java, but not being allowed to use anything but Hashmaps + java.lang.*

Scala on the other hand combines functional and object oriented in an extremely interesting way. It has a strong type system which enables tricks that probably will make your head spin.

And even if you don't use the really fancy stuff you have a super powerful language to work with.

So if you want to learn: Go with Scala

Answer (score 1):

The capabilities of the technology stack here are probably unimportant.  Both Scala and Node will allow you to implement a web interface / HTML5-based application for mobile devices.

So it boils down to your other requirement, "learn something new and exciting".  If you're not familiar with node or JavaScript, I'd suggest Node because ...

- JS is a much more marketable skill than Scala (currently)
- If you want other people to work on this code, more people know JS than Scala.
- You are only learning one new language instead of two. (You have to learn JS in either case to implement the front end.  With Node, that expertise carries over to the server as well.)

... and even if you are familiar with JS, working with Node will make you a much better JS developer.

My $.02.  You should get somebody who knows something about Scala to chime in here however.